# Flash Builder 4.6 message: “Workspace in use or cannot be created, chose a different one.”

Tags: flash-builder

Flash Builder show me this message when i try to launch it: “Workspace in use or cannot be created, chose a different one.” 
I already tried to uninstall and reinstall the program but the problem is still present. Also I have deleted the .lock file in the .metadata folder in the workspace folder but doesn't work. 
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try starting your Flash Builder as an Administrator. Worked for me.